# How to do a function that subtracts a given date from the current date

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-workbench

Here is what I have so far:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION StudentEnrollTime(startDate date)
RETURNS DATE
BEGIN
    RETURN (CURDATE() - startDate);
END$$    
DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to take in a date given within the functions parameters and subtract it by the current date. What is causing the Error?

Thank you for your help!

I tried to return the CURDATE() - the parameter -> StarDate but MySQL workbench does not like that for some reason...

Comment: How can subtracting dates return a date? What date is today minus yesterday?

Comment: What is an example parameter value, and the expected return value?

Comment: When you subtract dates, it returns the number of days between them, like the `DATEDIFF()` function.

Comment: An example parameter would be a date like 1992-02-21. An example of how I would like this code to work is:  1992-02-21 - 2022-12-7 = (Amount of time that has occurred between these 2 dates)